# Stable coin in substrate

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node

How can a stablecoin be developed on a Substrate-based blockchain? I came across [this question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/4283/2844), which suggests following the implementation approach of Acala. However, are there alternative methods to create a stablecoin apart from this route?

Comment: Highly depends on if you want to use a simpler issuer-backed stablecoins, or some kind of algorithmic stable-coin. In both cases, though, you would probably opt to use an instance of `pallet-balances` or `pallet-assets` and provide the mint/burn privileges to either the issuer or the runtime, respectively.

Comment: is the token created using `pallet-balances` or `pallet-assets` considered as stablecoin?